# Is there a way to avoid opening the _next in a new tab with FormSubmit?

Tags: html, forms

Using FormSubmit for a contact form on my static website, it does work and all but I don't like it that it redirects you to a new tab. Is it possible to have that _next tab close automatically? I tried disabling the recaptcha but that obviously didn't do it. Any ideas? Or an alternative for a contact form for my website without opening the e-mail client?

```html
<form target="_blank" action="https://formsubmit.co/hello@samplemail.com" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="textboxContacto" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="">
      <input type="text" name="numero" id="textboxContacto" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu número" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea placeholder="Cuéntanos tus dudas" id="textboxContacto" class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://website.com">
  <button type="submit" style="float:right;" class="button">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't like it that it redirects you to a new tab.

Then take `target="_blank"` out and it will load the new page in the *same* tab.

If you don't want to visit the page hosted by the service you are using then look for a solution that isn't free. I'm assuming they are funding the service by advertising at the people you send their way.

Comment: It's fine that it's redirected to them or anyhwere else, it has the option to do so. I was looking for that target="_blank" answer so that it's on the same page and it doesn't open a new tab :)